# PDF file without content in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

**UPDATE**

**Hello friends**,

I want to ask you for help.

I created a web form that generates PDF files. Everything is fine. Automatically Send PDFs via Email is OK. Unfortunately, the form fields that are not added to the models.Model are not included in the PDF (contents).

PDF documents display (postal_code) as blank field.

I don't know what to do. Where is the problem?

**model.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**forms.py**

```
CHOICES=[('item1','1xx'),
         ('item2','2xx')]

class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    postal_code = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['name', 'postal_code']
```

**create.html**

```
  <form action="." method="post" class="order-form">
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import task
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from oferty.models import Order
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings
import weasyprint
from io import BytesIO

@task
def order_created(order_id):

    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'NEW {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Hi  {}!\n\nBlablabla.\
                  Ident blabla {}.'.format(order.imię,
                                            order.id)
    email = EmailMessage(subject,
                         message,
                         'admin@myshop.com',
                         [order.email])

    html = render_to_string('orders/order/pdf.html', {'order': order})
    out = BytesIO()
    stylesheets = [weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')]
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(out,
                                           stylesheets=stylesheets)
    email.attach('order_{}.pdf'.format(order.id),
                 out.getvalue(),
                 'application/pdf')


    email.send()
```

**pdf.html**

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>
    {{ order.name }}<br>
    {{ order.postal_code }}
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you give me any hint of which way   ?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrderItem
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from cart.cart import Cart
from .tasks import order_created
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Order
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import weasyprint


def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                        product=item['product'],
                                        price=item['price'],
                                        quantity=item['quantity'])
            cart.clear()
            order_created.delay(order.id)
            return render(request,
                          'orders/order/created.html',
                          {'order': order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request,
                  'orders/order/create.html',
                  {'cart': cart, 'form': form})


@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('orders/order/pdf.html',
                            {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename= "order_{}.pdf"'.format(order.id)
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
    return response
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$',
        views.order_create,
        name='order_create'),
    url(r'^admin/order/(?P<order_id>\d+)/pdf/$',
        views.admin_order_pdf,
        name='admin_order_pdf'),
]
```

**Environment:**

```
Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

Help. Seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to store the postal code on the order you'll need to add the 'postal_code' field present on OrderCreateForm to the Order model.

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):

    CHOICES = [
        ('item1', '1xx'),
        ('item2', '2xx')
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CHOICES)
```

After that you'll only need to specify the radio select widget for that field your model form.

**forms.py**

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['name', 'postal_code']
        widgets = {
            'postal_code': forms.RadioSelect()
        }
```

Comment: It seems okay. Unfortunately it does not work. PDF still displays  blank field.

Comment: Sorry, I copied my files badly.. You may now see what's wrong.

Comment: Forgive me. All right, I forgot to add values as default during makemigrations. This is it. It works. You are great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

since postal_code is not a field of order model.You will have to pass it's value separately.Or you can add the field in the model. if you choose not to include this might help.

```
from celery import task
from oferty.models import Order
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings
import weasyprint
from io import BytesIO

@task
def order_created(order_id,postal_code):
    order = Oferta.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'New nr {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Hallow,  {}!\n\nBlaBlaBla.\
              BlaBlaBla {}.'.format(order.imię,
                                        order.id)
    email = EmailMessage(subject,
                     message,
                     'admin@myshop.com',
                     [order.email])

    html = render_to_string('orders/order/pdf.html', {'order': order,'postal_code':postal_code})
    out = BytesIO()
    stylesheets = [weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')]
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(out,
                                       stylesheets=stylesheets)

    email.attach('order_{}.pdf'.format(order.id),
             out.getvalue(),
             'application/pdf')

    email.send()
```

call the function with both the values

```
order_created(order_id=order_id,postal_code= postal_code)
```

and in the pdf.html replace

```
{{order.postal_code}}
```

with

```
{{postal_code}}
```

Comment: I receive in the console:  check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: order_created() missing 1 required positional argument: 'postal_code'

Comment: You have to pass the postal_code in the order_created function call order_created(order_id,postal_code)

Comment: Yes, of course, I noticed that. Unfortunately, I have this error: TypeError: order_created() missing 1 required positional argument: 'postal_code'

Comment: can you post the file from which you are calling the function?

Comment: I've also added views.py and urls.py. You may notice something important. I believe in you.

Comment: is this your updated view file? because I don't see any change in your posted task.py and views.py file

Comment: I'm new in Django. I'm just learning. I like Django but I'm a newbie. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142420/discussion-between-surbhit-wagle-and-kuba).

Comment: Excuse me. I've already updated the question. I'm very tired. Three days I am trying to build this form (configurator) correctly . Excuse me.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate the commitment. You forced me to work intensively and learn more. Motivation is the most important. Thank you Surbhit :)